# Pass a function template as a parameter in C++

Tags: c++, templates

For example, I want to get a list of maximum values from two sequences, `left` and `right`, and save the results in `max_seq`, which are all previously defined and allocated,

```
std::transform(left.begin(), left.end(), right.begin(), max_seq.begin(), &max<int>);
```

But this won't compile because the compiler says

```
 note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed
```

I know I can wrapper "std::max" inside a `struct` or inside a `lambda`. But is there a way `directly` use `std::max` without wrappers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`std::max`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max) has multiple overloads, so the compiler is unable to determine which one you want to call. Use `static_cast` to disambiguate and your code will compile.

```
static_cast<int const&(*)(int const&, int const&)>(std::max)
```

You should just use a lambda instead

```
[](int a, int b){ return std::max(a, b); }
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/81b3102bde4fc82b)

Comment: @Yakk Hmm, works without it too. Didn't know the type would be deduced from the cast, but it makes sense when you think about it.

Comment: Basically you are using overload resolution, which doesn't require `<int>` either.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Template expansion and instanciation occur at compile time. So you can pass a template function only to templates.

You could pass an instanciated (templated) function at run-time (then it is an "ordinary" C++ function).