# Ways to passing in >1 vectors in C++ lambda function

Tags: c++, lambda

I want to calculate the maximum of `s[i]*v[i]` from 2 vectors `s` and `v`.

I'm wondering if there is a way of utilizing lambda function in a similar form of:

`min(s.begin(), s.end(), [](){})` which can also include `v.begin()` and `v.end()`?

Comment: @Holt but there is :)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
#include <limits>
#include <numeric>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
int max = std::inner_product(s.begin(), s.end(), v.begin(), std::numeric_limits<int>::min(), 
        static_cast<int const&(*)(int const&, int const&)>(std::max), std::multiplies<int>());
```

Assuming ofcourse that `s` and `v` are vectors of `int` and are the same size.

**EDIT** I removed the lambdad `[](const int& a, const int& b){ return std::max(a, b); }`

Comment: This is so far the correct answer. `inner_product` was designed to solve the OP's very problem!

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25432689/1329652) covers how to pass `std::max` like you wish, and it's *ugly* because you have to disambiguate the overloads: `static_cast<int const&(*)(int const&, int const &)>(std::max<int>)`. Using a lambda is much cleaner and recommended in that very answer. You can pass the arguments to lambda by value to make it more concise. Any sane compiler will inline everything, so that neither `std::max` nor the lambda will exist as separate entities.

Comment: You can also add `<functional>` include for `std::multiplies` :)

Comment: While this works, I think it is an abuse of the notion of *inner product*.

Comment: &R it was the only way I could think of that was an expression (as opposed to a statement) which is what I assumed the OP wanted.

Comment: @Isaac, true. However, it's cryptic. I will be very upset if one of my programmers wrote such code.

Answer (score 2):

There is no simple, standard library function to do what you would like to do.

Seriously, what can be simpler and easier to understand than the following?

```
int maxProduct = std::numeric_limits<int>::min();
for ( size_t it = 0; it != s.size(); ++it )
{
   maxProduct = std::max(maxProduct, s[it]*v[it]);
}
```